# Separating DbContext in multiple projects

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a company MVC4 "template" which contains basic helpers, user functions etc, just stuff that is needed in every project.

Now I am trying to separate the `Users` part which consists of 3 parts: controllers/models/views, a business layer and a data layer.

Now I ran into the problem that I pulled out the data layer part and put it in a seperate project which will become a private Nuget package.

But the package won't know about the `DbContext` because it's in the DataLayer from the actual project website.

The DbContext for the website currently looks like this:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    ....
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    ....
    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

The `Languages` and `Users` will go in a separate project/NuGet package and `Reservations` will remain on the website as it is site specific.

The `Languages` and `Users` tables have no reference to each other, but `Reservations` has a reference to both `User` and to `Language`.

What are the options here to still keep a full Code-First model including migrations. Could I create multiple `DbContext` for every project/NuGet separately, will code-first migrations be able to pick this up, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Reservations contains links to Language and User classes then you will have to use the same Context.

If you want more loosely coupled implementation, then just include IDs instead of actual classes, then you can use separate contexts, but you will loose the ease of referencing objects and so on. The implementation really depends on how big your project is and how you plan on updating the solution.

Comment: Problem is that I have multiple websites using the same "backoffice", when a bug is updated I have to go through all these projects and update the bug in the source. If I use packages I won't have that problem.

Comment: You should use Repository model and Interfaces to separate the actual implementation. That way you can can hide implementation details (EF Context) from your front end sites. So instead of exposing DataContext to the frontend, you will return IBackofficeService, or something similar. You then create and implementation of that interface using your DataContext. You should also consider using some kind of IoC (Inversion of Control) library, Unity for example. In that can you can register your implementation and create a controller like this MyController(IBackofficeService service) in MVC.

Comment: Here is one guide on how to implement such approach with EF http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. You can also checkout the project I'm working on for the more real world application using the repository model [virtocommerce](http://virtocommerce.codeplex.com)

Comment: I will have a look at it thanks, I am already using Unity yeah.

Comment: I actually think it's not possible. I have a table `Posts` which contain the `User` who wrote it, but `Users` also contains a list of `Post` and will give a circular reference.

Comment: It is possible. For those relations you will need to use EF Code First fluent API to tell DB to not create cascading relations. That is a restriction in SQL Server.

Comment: But they are separate projects, will the Fluent api still work?

Comment: Hey @Rogier21, do you remember how did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hey @fabricio, I basically didn't. For what I remember it was next to impossible to separate contexts, especially when you are using migrations.

Comment: @Rogier21 damn it! thanks for your answer anyway.. I had something in mind that I won't be able to do it the way I wanted to.